# Display students records between two dates on Python GUI from Sqlite3database

Tags: python

I built student registration system in Python and Sqlite3. Now I can only display on Python Treeview students records on specific date only.

**PROBLEM**: I want to know how display students records between two dates on Python Treeview from Sqlite3 database.

I always appreciate your help.

Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry 
import sqlite3


my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("900x650")  # Size of the window 
my_w.title("www.plus2net.com")  # Adding a title
sel=tk.StringVar()
cal=DateEntry(my_w,selectmode='day',textvariable=sel)
cal.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=30)
def my_upd(*args): # triggered when value of string varaible changes
    if(len(sel.get())>4):
        dt=cal.get_date() # get selected date object from calendar
        dt1=dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") #format for MySQL date column 
        dt1=(dt1,)
        dt2=dt.strftime("%d-%B-%Y") #format to display at label 
        l1.config(text=dt2) # display date at Label
        con=sqlite3.connect(database="school.db")
        cur=con.cursor()
        cur.execute ("SELECT * FROM student WHERE regisdate=?",dt1)
        r_set=cur.fetchall()
       
        for item in trv.get_children(): # delete all previous listings
            trv.delete(item)
       
        for dt in r_set: 
            trv.insert("", 'end',id=dt[0],text=dt[0],
                       values =(dt[0],dt[1],dt[2],dt[3]))
        
l1=tk.Label(my_w,font=('Times',22,'bold'),fg='blue')
l1.grid(row=0,column=1)
trv = ttk.Treeview(my_w, selectmode ='browse')
  
trv.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=20,pady=20)
# number of columns
trv["columns"] = ("0", "1", "2","3")
trv['height']  =20
# Defining heading
trv['show'] = 'headings'
  
# width of columns and alignment 
trv.column("0", width = 30, anchor ='c')
trv.column("1", width = 80, anchor ='c')
trv.column("2", width = 80, anchor ='c')
trv.column("3", width = 80, anchor ='c')
trv.heading("0", text ="ID")
trv.heading("1", text ="Name")
trv.heading("2", text ="Contact")
trv.heading("3", text ="RegisDate")  

sel.trace('w',my_upd)

l2=tk.Label(my_w,font=('Times',22,'bold'),fg='red')
l2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='ne',pady=20)

my_w.mainloop()
```